# How do I convert a "Print to PDF'ed" file back to an unflattened regular PDF file?

Tags: pdf, quickbooks, quickbooks-online

My paystub from Quickbooks allows a download of the paystub as a PDF. However, when I try to upload this PDF file to a software by Snappt (they try to detect tenant application fraud), I am given an error that says my PDF file was saved using "Print to PDF"
See image below:
[image]

I need to find a way to obtain a proper PDF from Quickbooks to upload. Or is there another way around this?

Comment: They are probably just checking the "Creator" and "Producer" fields in either the PDF plain metadata, or XML metadata, or both. Try `cpdf -remove-metadata in.pdf AND -set-creator "" AND -set-producer "" -o out.pdf`